# What are the separations of concerns for testing a component that consumes additional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, ember.js, integration-testing

**When writing tests for a web-component (parent) that consumes other web-components (children) should the parent's tests provide coverage to ensure the children are rendering/configured properly?**

Here's an example, it might be a poor example, but's lets try: Say we have a component (WebComponent/React/Vue/Ember, any component will do here): `<Carousel @options=options>` which renders various children components: such as `<Video @options=options>` and `<Image @option=options>` and many others.

The Carousel component receives  a set of `options` from the model, such as `iconColor` and `objectFit`, and passes that in a datadown fashion to share with and be consumed by the child components.

**Should I be testing “user can configure iconcolor for image” in both my tests for the `<Image>` and `<Carousel>`?**

It seems awkward to me and not very DRY to test for successful configuration of `iconcolor` in the respective tests for both `<Carousel>` and `<Image>`. If the `<Carousel>` component consumes 5 different components, its tests start scaling in size, especially if we add more config options.

But at the same time is seem very brittle not to have test coverage in both.  For example, if we rely on `<Image>`'s test coverage for configuration of iconColor, `<Image>` could be refactored anytime and a developer could change the name of the property for setting iconColor, adjust the tests to match. The developer would be unaware that `<Carousel>` has a dependancy on `<Image>`'s API for configuring iconColor.

Comment: more context, this would be for an Integration test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're aiming for the highest code coverage possible or the integration of the parent component and the child component(s) is paramount (i.e., if it doesn't hand something off to a child component the right way then things could go **very** wrong) then you should absolutely be testing the multiple possible configurations between the parent and child components.

I understand what you mean by saying it doesn't feel very DRY (and in some forms or cases it really isn't DRY), but you should think of it this way:

The cases where you isolate a child component and test various configurations is where your tests should be primarily concerned with testing **what** those components are doing with the configurations when it comes to the DOM or testing the boundaries with any services, etc.

To use your example, if I have an `<Image>` component, I will write my integration tests to assert its behavior when I give it particular props or options. For example, what happens if I pass in these parameters?

```
<Image @width=100 @height=100 @onClick={{action "doSomething"}} />
```

The integration test should test that these values have some effect on whatever it renders and how the user interacts with the image. Perhaps `width` and `height` set the width and height of an `<img>` tag in terms of a percentage and clicking on the image is supposed to call an action that's provided to this component.

On the other hand, why do we need to test whether or not my `<Carousel />` component can render an `<Image />` component if I already have an integration test that tests everything the `<Image />` component can do?

The answer is to test the integration between these two components and to make sure the parent component is wired up correctly with the children. In other words, it's to make sure `<Carousel />` is handing any and all options to its child components **correctly**.

In some cases this may not be such a big deal and in reality I think a lot of the time testing here can be overlooked, but like I stated earlier, if the integration is critical, then you have to test how the parent is passing options to the children.

To illustrate how this can provide coverage, say I wire up the template of my `<Carousel />` component like so:

**carousel.hbs**

```
<Image @width=50 @height=50 @onChange={{action "doSomething"}} />
```

Looking at this you can clearly see what happened -- I meant to wire that action up as `@onClick`, not `@onChange`. Yet all my integration tests for `<Image />` are passing so without testing how the `<Carousel />` component passes the properties down to its children I would be lacking coverage and this bug has a higher chance of making it out to production.

The part that makes it not DRY is looking at the integration test for the parent and having to write very similar code (i.e., making sure that when I click the image it calls the correct action). Sometimes there's no real nice way around doing this -- and I think those sorts of scenarios are where the integration might be overlooked. Other times there are things that can be done to reduce the amount of duplicate test code.

In Ember, sometimes passing in a property is tied to a particular class name for the child component (in addition to other functionality). Rather than duplicating a test that checks "is the child's component behavior correct?", we can write an integration test that checks "did the child component receive the correct property?"

For example, if our parent component was wired up like so:

**carousel.hbs**

```
<Image @someFlag=true />
```

Let's say this `@someFlag` property does the following:

- adds a class to the image
- makes the image grow in size on mouse hover
- makes a network request to report some user metrics when the image is clicked

The integration test for the `<Image />` component is going to test all of these things when `@someFlag` is true. Rather than duplicate that exact test, however, the integration test for our `<Carousel />` component can simply check: "does the `<Image />` component have the expected class name?" This is actually a very common way to reduce the amount of duplicate test code you need to write.

There are of course cases where you don't *need* to test the integration. If `<Carousel />` was just passing off whatever it received to its children then you have an argument against writing an integration test for this sort of thing.